# JSONArray Name Value Pair modification

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a string which follows a certain pattern and I want to write the substring into a JSON array object.

I have each substring in an array using regular expression.

Now I want to write all these substring in a json file using a jsonarray object.

I have been able to do it fine, but the name value pairs in json viewer shows

```
0 abcde
1 pqrs
```

I want to modify these names ( i.e. 0 and 1) to specific string. How to do it?

Below is my code.

```
String introduction="<p>abcde</p><p>pqrs</p><p>xyz</p>";
JSONArray intro_paragraphs = new JSONArray();   
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("<p>")+ "(.*?)"+ Pattern.quote("</p>")).matcher(introduction);
while(m.find())
    {
    String match_intro = m.group(1);
    intro_paragraphs.put(match_intro);
    obj.put("Section_Detailed_Introduction", intro_paragraphs);
    }
```

Output is:::

```
[]Section_Detailed_Introduction
0 abcde
1 pqrs
2 xys
```

I want:::

```
para_1 abcde
para_2 pqrs
para_3 xyz
```

Comment: The code you posted does not produce any output. How is that output produced? As for building a JSONArray containing Strings, that looks fine. There is no need for the `obj.put()` to be in the loop; just do that once.

Comment: Okay...but any hint on modifying name-value pair names??

Comment: JSONArray is not a name-value pair type of structure. A Map is, or a JSONObject. Is `obj` a Map or something? You don't show its declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some minor modification on the code you can achieve this

```
String introduction="<p>abcde</p><p>pqrs</p><p>xyz</p>";
JSONObject intro_paragraphs = new JSONObject(); 
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("<p>")+ "(.*?)"+  Pattern.quote("</p>")).matcher(introduction);
int i=1;
String key="para_";
while(m.find())
{
    String match_intro = m.group(1);
    intro_paragraphs.put(key+i, match_intro);
    i++;
}
obj.put("Section_Detailed_Introduction", intro_paragraphs);
```